# How to run Asynctask for show "data is reading" dialog in running thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread which is continuously running ,when i will send the command to get the data, data starts to come. I wanna to show this process to the Asynctask show that user can understand data is reading . How can i achieve this please help me . For now i am using timer. but timer will work for fixed time. but if my data is less, that time, timer will take the same time that i don't want . If anyone have any idea please let me know....  Thanks in advance for help

```
    I had use this but because of running thread message getting continuously.
     
    
        public static class Test extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
                ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                DataBaseController dataBaseController;
        
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog( context);
                    progressDialog.setTitle( "Sync Data" );
                    progressDialog.setMessage( "Syncing..." );
                    progressDialog.setCancelable( false );
                    progressDialog.setIcon( android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info );
                    progressDialog.show();
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }
        
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                    dataBaseController = DataBaseController.getnstance( context );
// seperating the data which is getting from getResponse method
                    if (strings[0] != null) {
                        String ok = strings[0].replace( "OK", "" ).replace( "Scale id,Rec.No,Date,Time,Bill No.,Item No.,Plu,Name,Qty,Rate,Amount,Void", "" );
                        String[] data = ok.split( "," );
                        Log.i( "TEST", strings[0] );
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            char c = strings[0].charAt( i );
                            if (c == ',') {
                                int id = Integer.parseInt( data[0] );
                                int rec_no = Integer.parseInt( (data[1]) );
                                String Date = data[2];
                                if (Date != null)
                                    Date = custom_date_format( Date );
                                String Time = data[3];
                                int Bill_No = Integer.parseInt( data[4] );
                                int Item_No = Integer.parseInt( data[5] );
                                int Plu = Integer.parseInt( data[6] );
                                String Name = data[7];
                                String weight_type = data[8];
                                int Unit;
                                if (weight_type=="Kg"){
                                    Unit=0;
                                }else{
                                    Unit=1;
                                }
                                float Qty = Float.parseFloat( data[9] );
                                float Rate = Float.parseFloat( data[10] );
                                float Amount = Float.parseFloat( data[11] );
                                String Void = data[12];
                                PLU plu = new PLU( id, rec_no, Date, Time, Bill_No, Item_No, Plu, Name, Unit, Qty, Rate, Amount );
                                boolean check = dataBaseController.isBillExist( plu.getRec_no() );
                                if (!check) {
                                    dataBaseController.Trasaction(plu);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return String.valueOf( strings );
                }
        
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (result != null) {
                        Toast.makeText( context, "Mission successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText( context, "Mission failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        
                    }
                }
            }
    
      *******Thread which is connected*****************
    
         private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
                private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
                private final InputStream mmInStream;
                private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
                boolean get_actualdata = false;
                private boolean stop = false;
                private boolean hasReadAnything = false;
        
                public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
                    Log.d( TAG, "create ConnectedThread" );
                    mmSocket = socket;
                    InputStream tmpIn = null;
                    OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        
                    // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
                    try {
                        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                        // tmpIn.skip( 22 );
                        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e( TAG, "temp sockets not created", e );
                    }
        
                    mmInStream = tmpIn;
                    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
                }
        
        
                public void shutdown() {
                    stop = true;
                    if (!hasReadAnything) return;
                    if (mmInStream != null) {
                        try {
                            mmInStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e( TAG, "close() of InputStream failed." );
                        }
                    }
                }
        
        
                public void run() {
                    boolean send_validation = true;
                    int version;
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            version = readfunction(); // reading the  version response after sending command on bluetooth
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            connectionLost();
                            break;
                        }
                        if (version == 0) {
                            if (send_validation && !get_actualdata) {
        
                                StringParsing( str.toString() );// it will seperate the version 
                                get_actualdata = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            try {
                                readfunction();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if (get_actualdata && send_validation) {
        
                            try {
                                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                                    int ok = Handle_OK();//if getting ok
                                    String status;
                                    if (ok == 1) {
                                        status = "OK";
                                        mHandler.readLine( status );
                                    } else {
                                        status = "Not Recognised with device";
                                        mHandler.readLine( status );
                                    }
                                    getReportResponse();
                                }
        
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                connectionLost();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                break;
                            }
        
                        }
        
        
                    }
                }
    //this method calling in running thread , it will response when command send by click on button
         public void getReportResponse() throws IOException {
                    boolean with_header = false;
                    try {
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( mmInStream ) );
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            // String finalLine = line;
                            if (reset_the_reader_flag) { //if reset_the_header will true
                                with_header = false;
                            }
                            String f_line = custom_filter(line);
                            if (!f_line.isEmpty()){
                                if (with_header) { // if with_header flag will false then it will jump in else
                                  //  dataparse.ReportData( f_line);
                                    new Handler( Looper.getMainLooper()).post( new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
    //Asynctask when command send this method will run
                                            TabularFragment.Test data = new TabularFragment.Test();
                                            data.execute( f_line );
                                        }
                                    } );
                                } else {
                                    // if header matches set the with_header flag true, then exist from else part and again check with_heaer flag
                                    // if header will not match, will jump in else and read the data that is without header.
                                    if (f_line.matches( "Scale(.*)" )) {
                                        with_header = true;
                                    } else {//
                                        dataparse.Data( f_line );
                                    }
                                    reset_the_reader_flag = false;
        
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            mmInStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You are already showing a progress dialog, and I can't see any timer in your code.

Comment: The code looks fine to me and should satisfy your requirements, where is the timer you talking about?

Comment: @KgaboL please check again i have posted all code

Comment: still cant see the timer